# When does the AWS .NET SDK load credential files? Is it on startup or on initializing client or...?

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

As my title states, we are using the AWS .NET SDK and on our web.config configured a profile that points to a credentials file(see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html using credentials file) on the disk(so out of the source code). This seems to work fine but we are rotating these keys every x period so we need to change the keys within the file. My question is does de AWS .NET SDK notice that the file is changed and automatically load the new credentials or when does it actually load? In other words, if we change the credentials in this file do we need to do additional steps for the application to actually use them?

What I tried now is start up the application locally, change the credentials to a faulty one and calls are still going thru without a problem. Next, I stopped my application and rebuilded in with the same file having faulty credentials. After doing this the application is still able to make correct calls so I'm wondering how this works as if it is falling back on credentials that did work. Or maybe I just didn't test right.

We are using .net framework 4.6.2 application using the aws sdk version 3.3

Also what i forgot to mention is that for each request we initialize the client like this:

```
using (AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient client = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(regionEndpoint))
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is creating a client like that will cause the credentials to be read from the credentials file when the first client is created.

The longer answer is when you create without credentials the client uses the [FallbackCredentialsFactory](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Credentials/FallbackCredentialsFactory.cs) class to find credentials either through the credentials file or environment like EC2 instance metadata. The FallbackCredentialsFactory has a static instance of [Amazon.Runtime.CredentialManagement.CredentialProfileStoreChain](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/CredentialManagement/_bcl%2Bnetstandard/CredentialProfileStoreChain.cs) which is what gets the credentials for a profile.

If you want to something different you could have your code create an instance of CredentialProfileStoreChain before creating a client and use that to get the credentials and pass those credentials into the client.